# Не получется обьявить метод Java

Tags: java, методы

Всем привет. Вопрос наверняка дурацкий, у меня был перерыв от кодинга в год и сейчас маловато помню и соображаю. Почему не получается обьявить обычный метод? Баг идеешки или баг мозга?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = in.nextInt();

        void hello(){
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ............второе

Answer (score 3):

Метод внутри метода объявляете? Такое можно в разных языках, но не в *Java*

Comment: Точняк..... Извините , спасибо)